# Php variable with operation in declaration of a drop down box

Tags: php

How can I put a variable with operation in the declaration of a drop down box?
I have a drop down box with the months and when user selects March, the result of the code below is 2+1. I get this is handled as string function but I don't know how to make php handle it as it would result in 3.

```
echo "<option value=\"$i+1\">$month[$i]</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the operation out of quotes for it to evaluate as expected:

```
echo "<option value='" . ($i + 1) . "'>$month[$i]</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't interpolate arithmetic in PHP double quoted strings - you have to break it into concatenated strings or do the math before your echo statement.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

You need to let PHP evaluate the `+` as an operator, not part of the string:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . ($i+1) . "\">$month[$i]</option>\n";
```

Only variables (`$foo`, anything that starts with a `$`) inside double quoted strings. What you have in your code is "print the value of `$i`, then the string `+1`". By using concatenation, the echo statement can interpret `$i+1` literally and add one to `$i`.